# Timer not running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class PipeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxTime = 1;
    private float timer = 0;
    public GameObject pipe;
    public float height;

    void Update()
    {
        if (timer > maxTime)
        {
            GameObject newpipe = Instantiate(pipe);
            newpipe.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-height, height), 0);
            Destroy(newpipe, 15);
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`Timer` never passes max time, so the code in the update method never executes.

Comment: Looking at your code, I do not see where you update the value of timer, that's probably the reason why timer never exceeds maxTime. Give more context. The code as it stands will never have timer exceed maxTime unless it is updated elsewhere. Share more code

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat way of doing "cooldowns" or "timers":

```
public class PipeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float futureTimestamp;
    public GameObject pipe;
    public float height;

    void Start() 
    {
        futureTimestamp = SetFutureTimestamp(5);
    }

    void Update()
    {
            if (Time.time > maxTime)
            {
                GameObject newpipe = Instantiate(pipe);
                newpipe.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-height, height), 0);
                Destroy(newpipe, 15);
            }
        }
    }
    
    void SetFutureTimestamp(float seconds) {
        futureTimestamp = Time.time + seconds;
    }
```

Basically setting a timestamp in the future and checking if current time is larger than future time each update. `Time.time > futureTimestamp`

Answer (score 0):

You could use class `Timer` and

```
Timer.Start();
```

create a global int variable

```
int tik = 0
```

and using the event `Timer_Tik` to count how many seconds passed (`tik++`).
To control the interval you should use `Timer.Interval = 1000;` witch is one second and final

```
if (tik > maxTime)
```